# How do I make Thunar display file sizes in #iB instead of #B?

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

Thunar's file sizes are so misleading, especially when I receive a file reported as 64.1 MB but only receive a 61.1 MB file.

so how can I make Thunar display in #iB so I can see proper file sizes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple fix, use another file manager.

Dolphin more than takes over where Thunar leaves off:
- displaying file sizes in (K/M/G)iB
- displaying a progress bar showing your active drive's usage
- providing many more options for extendability and customization
and much more.